# Bootstrap Align Image with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align an image on the left side with text using boostrap, and when page is viewed on mobile devices the images becomes centred on top of the text !

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    </class>
     <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="imgAbt">
        <img  width="220" height="220" src="img/me.jpg">
     </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-8"><p>Lots of text here...With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have also tried `.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9` along with `.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3` , however I still was not able to achieve desired results, [similar to this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Lu2.jpg)

Comment: What are those ".span 4" and "span 8" classnames doing in there? And there is no tag <class>

Comment: @ravb79, my bad it was old code I tried. Updated

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have two choices, either correct your markup so that it uses correct elements and utilizes the Bootstrap grid system:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <h1>About Me</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="imgAbt">
                <img width="220" height="220" src="img/me.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>Lots of text here...With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you wish the text to closely wrap the image, change your markup to:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img style='float:left;width:200px;height:200px; margin-right:10px;' src="img/me.jpg" />
            <p>Lots of text here...With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

use the **grid-system** of **boostrap** , more information [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

for example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">here img</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">here text</div>
</div>
```

in this way when the page will shrink the second div(the text) will be found under the first(the image)

Answer (score 3):

Try using .pull-left to left align image along with text.

Ex:

```
<p>At the time all text elements goes here.At the time all text elements goes here. At the time all text elements goes here.<img src="images/hello-missing.jpg" class="pull-left img-responsive" style="padding:15px;" /> to uncovering the truth .</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="container">
          <h1>About me</h1>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="pull-left ">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="col-lg-3" class="img-    responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                <p class="col-md-4">Lots of text here... </p> 
                </div>

          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is helpful for you

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </div><!--END page-header-->
        <div class="row" id="features">
                <div class="col-sm-6 feature">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Web Design" class="img-circle">
                </div><!--END feature-->

                <div class="col-sm-6 feature">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
                </div><!--END feature-->
            </div><!--end features-->
    </div><!--end container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

i am a new bee ;p . And i faced the same problem. And the solution is BS Media objects. please see the code..

```
<div class="media">
   <div class="media-left media-top">
    <img src="something.png" alt="@l!" class="media-object" width="20" height="50"/>
    </div>
   <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="media-heading">Beside Image</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
     <h1>About Me</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="imgAbt">
                <img width="100%" height="100%" src="img/me.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>Lots of text here...With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```