# why the image doesn't align to the right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i tried text-align an all other options i know ,but nothing happend
i want to align the imag to the right of the media-body

```
 <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>

                <h3 align="center">This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="media">
                <div class=" media-right" style="text-align:right;">
                        <a href="#" >
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                         src="img/buffet.png" alt="buff" >
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading">Weekend Grand Buffet<span class="label label-danger">New</span></h2>
                <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
                 <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#">More &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640175/bootstrap-align-image-with-text